# When I add text to blender it disappears when I start the game engine

Tags: game-engine

When designing my game using blender 2.79 when I start the game engine the text object added disappears:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you attach your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: please don't duplicate questions... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92830/text-disappers-when-i-play-game-in-blender-2-79

Comment: Your file is fine on my laptop. I can see the text.

Comment: I can see the text as well when pressing p. Maybe try to update your graphics driver or reset blender settings?

Comment: I just solved the issue. I had earlier changed the ui font of my blender. So it made the text object invisible when I render. I had to reset my preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the issue. I had earlier changed the ui font of my blender. So it made the text object invisible when I render. I had to reset my preferences/settings.